# changing cost function in xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

I'm using the newest version of xgboost package in python 2.7 and based on my problem, I'm going to change xgboost cost function to use my own defined cost function. Couple of questions:

In which part of the xgboost package should I find and change the cost function?
After changing the cost function, how can I add the updated code to the xgboost package to use the new training function instead of xgboost's pre-defined function?

Comment: Reading the docs will help

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436629/how-to-write-a-custom-evaluation-metric-in-python-for-xgboost), just to recap:

Define your your customized cost function, e.g.:

```
 def new_cost(y_pred, y_true):
    # perform calculation for new cost
    return 'new_cost', score
```

Then pass it to the feval argument (see [official doc](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)) for training like:

```
model = xgboost.train(params, dtrain, num_rounds, watchlist, feval=new_cost)
```

There are many examples out there if you search harder for more concrete use cases.

Comment: Here you can also see an example of a custom objective in xgboost https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py

Comment: `feval` is used for customized evaluation function. **feval (function) – Customized evaluation function.** For defining customized cost function use **obj (function) – Customized objective function**.