# Custom loss function for XGBoost

Tags: xgboost

I am looking for code to implement a custom loss function instead of just classification error, or cross entropy for gradient boosted classification trees.
We are trying to model regime detection in financial markets based on economic indicators. The intended loss function is that if the model outputs a probability of each class of risk as `p_low`, `p_medium`, and `p_high`, then the loss function we are looking for is `( p_low * Returns(portfolio_low_risk) + p_medium * Returns(portfolio_medium_risk) + p_high * Returns(portfolio_high_risk) )`
We already have a data frame of Returns(portfolio_i_risk).

Comment: Welcome!  I think the main question is a duplicate of  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30630/changing-cost-function-in-xgboost
But if you have more specific questions relating to this specific loss function, please clarify, especially how the `Returns` frames are structured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing cost function in xgboost](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30630/changing-cost-function-in-xgboost)